# how to divide points to answers in forms?

Tags: javascript, forms

I know how to do it in php, but not in JS, so i need some help to get started.

I got 10 questions that all have 10 points to give to a,b,c or d.

```
1         2         3
a.  3     a. 0      a.  2
b.  1     b. 0      b.  3
c.  5     c. 0      c.  2
d.  1     d. 10     d.  3
```

etc, so it all adds up to the 10 points that can be divided!

Questions look like :

```
Give points to these colors:
[  ] a) green
[  ] b) blue
[  ] c) red
[  ] d) orange
[10] <-- points that still can be divided, and a check V when its good.
```

Format can be in select, input=number field, doesn't really matter, and it has to be checked when pressing submit if all points are divided over the answers, so I can use it as $_POST answers with php and do my magic, so it doesn't have to reload the whole form over and over.

I got really no idea how/where to start since I can't find anything similar online.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one using textboxes and simple error checking. Is this what you are looking for?

```js
function check() {
  var green = Number(document.forms["myform"]["green"].value);
 var blue = Number(document.forms["myform"]["blue"].value);
 var red = Number(document.forms["myform"]["red"].value);
 var orange = Number(document.forms["myform"]["orange"].value);
 var total = green + blue + red + orange;
 if (total == 10) {
   return true;
 } else {
   alert("You have allocated " + total + " points. You must allocate exactly ten.");
  return false;
 }
}
```

```html
<form name="myform" onsubmit="return check()">
<p>Give points to these colors:</p>
<input name="green" size="2" type="text" /> a) green<br />
<input name="blue" size="2" type="text" /> b) blue<br />
<input name="red" size="2" type="text" /> c) red<br />
<input name="orange" size="2" type="text" /> d) orange<br />
<button type="submit">OK</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes I could make this work, but this is 1 question so i gotta repeat this 10 times with different vars, or is there any cleaner way to do it?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. You can use an array instead of variables if you are concerned about using too many different variables.

Comment: Well, its 10 questions with a,b,c,d answers, so i could name the forms 1a, 1b, 1c, 1d and do the var total1 = 1a + 1b + 1c + 1d; and repeat this for question 2 with 2a, 2b, etc, and then var total2 = 2a + 2b + 2c + 2d; etc